# Multivariate Time series forecasting- Statistical methods

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, statsmodels, forecast-combination

I was trying to forecast the truck numbers required at each distribution location...for that I was forecasting the shipments(number of units) at each location and dividing it by a factor to get the truck load...

Currently I was considering only the shipments but I thought it would be better to include open sales orders as an additional variable in the existing time series data... So for this which statistical model available to consider.. Will Arimax or Sarimax work?

Forecast periods will be 7 days in week.. please suggest how to approach this problem using traditional statistical forecasting methods.

Thank you

Comment: I think there is something like Gaussian Processes for multiple target variables. I have played around with this in order to predict exchange rates between different currencies (where the target variables depend on each other)... You could check https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.03471

Comment: If you were using (S)ARIMA until now (without the additional variable), SARIMA(X) is a natural extension.